# Object's variable changing method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, class, variables, object

I have a class named Movie:

```
class Movie 
    attr_accessor :title, :director, :date_of_issue, :register_number
    def initialize(title, director, date_of_issue, register_number)
        @title, @director, @date_of_issue, @register_numver = title, director, date_of_issue, register_number
    end
    def Basic_info
        puts "Title : #{@tytul}, Director: #{@autor}"
    end
end
```

I want to create a method which changes the existing Movie object's variables, without creating an entirely new object. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Your method `Basic_info` should actually be `basic_info` in order to follow best practices of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a method for that, you were on the right track, corrected a few errors though

```
class Movie  
  attr_accessor :title, :director, :date_of_issue, :register_number 
  def initialize(title, director, date_of_issue, register_number) 
    @title, @director, @date_of_issue, @register_numver = title, director, date_of_issue, register_number 
  end 
  def basic_info 
    puts "Title : #{@title}, Director: #{@director}" 
  end 
end  

movie = Movie.new "title", "director", "", 0
movie.director = "Martin Scorsese"
movie.title = "Goodfellas"
movie.date_of_issue = "1990"
movie.basic_info

#=>Title : Goodfellas, Director: Martin Scorsese
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW. "Goodfellas is one of my fav movies .